# How to Use Autocomplete in Jqgrid from Share Point and return the retrieved Json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm currently retrieving data using REST Services from share Point and using the filter in the xml

```
ex http:<<Server name>>/<list data. svc/<List>>?$search =<name>.
```

The data return type is "json" in ajax call The corresponding field is returned. My xml looks like as below.

```
<entry>
  <id></id>
  <title></title>
  <content>
    <m: properties>
      <name>
      </name>
      <number></number>
      <address></address>
   </m: properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

After Filtering using the URL the xml looks like below where the name filed is filtered.

```
<entry>
  <id></id>
  <title></title>
  <content>
    <m: properties>
      <name>
      </name>
    </m: properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

My question is how to filter only name filed from json data and populate as autocomplete